# Set data value of entity reference field with rules

Tags: rules

Is there a way that you can "Set data value" of an entity reference field using rules. So I would like to set a newly created node's entity reference field to another node's entity reference field.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would say the answer is yes. However, for something as complicated as Rules your question is very vague.

Comment: Hi,

Sorry for the vagueness! I have a content type called "Parent" and a content type called "Child" (This is just for this example). I have downloaded the Rules_link module which places a link on a node of your choice. When clicked it triggers an event. In this case the link would be placed on the parent node and when clicked, this should create a new entity which would be a child node. This child node will contain an entity reference field which will reference to the parent node. But I cannot find a way to set the data value of the child node's reference field. 

Thanks for replying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't work out how to do it with Rules, maybe try a custom module. It's been suggested to me that you could use `hook_node_update()`, or `hook_node_insert()` to populate that field.

Check http://drupal.org/node/1388924.

Answer (score 1):

[Using entity references in rules](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/using-entity-reference-in-rules)  & [More rule Links](http://dev.nodeone.se/en/more-rules-link) this might be of some help....